# Sending html template via amazon ses

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using the below code to send plan text but it's not working in html template..

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String username = "test";  // Replace with your SMTP username.
        String password = "test";  // Replace with your SMTP password.
        String host = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
        int port = 25;

        using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(host, port))
        {
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            client.Send
            (
                      "sales@imagedb.com",  // Replace with the sender address.
                      "rohit@imagedb.com",    // Replace with the recipient address.
                      "Testing Amazon SES through SMTP",
                      "This email was delivered through Amazon SES via the SMTP end point."
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [AlternateView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.alternateview.aspx)s with the .NET SmtpClient to send HTML messages. The mail client will render the appropriate views that it can support.

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates how to create a message with a text view and an HTML view, and then send the message via Amazon SES.

```
        string host = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
        int port = 25;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("ses-smtp-username", "ses-smtp-password");
        var sender = new MailAddress("sender@example.com", "Message Sender");
        var recipientTo = new MailAddress("recipient+one@example.com", "Recipient One");
        var subject = "HTML and TXT views";

        var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<p>This message is <code>formatted</code> with <strong>HTML</strong>.</p>", Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        var txtView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is a plain text message.", Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.From = sender;
        message.To.Add(recipientTo);
        message.AlternateViews.Add(txtView);
        message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        using (var client = new SmtpClient(host, port))
        {
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            client.Send(message);
        }
```